# Error in log file

Tags: logging

Do you know any other error except the emergency stop, which does not contain information about the line number in the log file, where the error has been received?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking. Are you asking about a particular problem or are you asking about the different types of errors that can occur? If the former then please provide details of the error and a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that generates it.

Comment: @Andrew
I want to determine if there is a group of errors for which the log file does not record the line number.
For example, this error has a row number: 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.9 \ed

I only know about the Emergency stop that does not record the line number but i do not know if it's the only exception.

Comment: Generally, whether the line number is recorded depends on the code generating the error. So a class or package might or might not include that information when generating the error. Or did you mean only those errors generated by the kernel?

Comment: I mean especially LaTex errors that are generating by TeX Live.

Comment: TeX Live is a collection of LaTeX binaries and packages (and documentation). TeX won't give any LaTeX errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all tex errors include such a line number if they occur while a file is being processed, including emergency stop.

For example this document gives an emergency stop after trying to input a non-existent file

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\batchmode \input zzzzzzzzz
\end{document}
```

the log shows that the error is on line 5 ( `l.5` )

```
! Emergency stop.
l.5 \batchmode \input zzzzzzzzz

*** (job aborted, file error in nonstop mode)
```

The errors that do not show a line number occur after the file has been read, typically due to a missing `\end{document}` in latex.

This document shows `<*>` rather than a line number, denoting an error when tex would have been reading from the terminal if it were not in batch mode.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\batchmode
```

produces the log

```
! Emergency stop.
<*> file

*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)
```

If you are not in batch mode so that TeX is accepting terminal input, then *any* TeX error can be produced showing `<*>` rather than a line number as the following terminal session shows

```
$ latex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
**\relax
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.12> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.

*\zzzzz
! Undefined control sequence.
<*> \zzzzz

? 

*\def\zzz}
! Missing { inserted.
<*> \def\zzz}

? x
No pages of output.
Transcript written on texput.log.
```